# In a unified process, what sort of UML models assist in the 5 disciplines?

Tags: uml, rational-unified-process

I read there are 5 disciplines in a unified process, Requirements, Analysis, design, Implementation, and test.

I've basically done the following UML's and I'm trying to add an explanation of how I adhered to the unified process. I did the following UML's for my project: Use case, Analysis class, Design class, Activity, Sequence, Deployment, state machine, and component.

I can already tell based on content that the use case falls into the categories of requirements. Analysis class falls into the category of analysis. Design class in design. But what about the other 2 disciplines? I am having some trouble understanding unified process. But if I were to assign the UML's to a discipline, what would they be assigned to.

Comment: Although this question is old. it seems appropriate to comment so that others aren't led astray. Some of this question's assertions are unusual and seem to convey a misunderstanding of the [Rational Unified Process (RUP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Unified_Process). Because no sources are cited, I'll avoid point-counterpoint and just offer this quote, "_RUP is not a single concrete prescriptive process, but rather an adaptable process framework, intended to be tailored ... RUP is a specific implementation of the Unified Process._"

Answer (score 0):

Implementation will be a mix of class and component and deployment diagrams. For test there's nothing in pure UML. You can create your own profile for it. Basically it ends up in sort of use case diagram for business with traces to requirements being marked in some way. Unit testing can trace classes to requirements. This is a wide open area where you can write more than one thesis about.